Flutter: fvm flutter run get error " Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.18."
I use "flutterSdkVersion": "3.3.10" with fvm at MacOS
The Problem is when i run "fvm flutter run" i get the following Error
enter image description here
When i run dart --version i get "Dart SDK version: 2.18.6 (stable) (Tue Dec 13 21:15:14 2022 +0000) on "macos_arm64"" - The right SDK Version for this Flutter Version
I already cleaned the Cache from the Project with my Clean Up Script and the global Dart cache with dart pub cache clean.
I have this cleanup Script
# Run Flutter commands
fvm flutter clean
fvm flutter pub cache repair
fvm flutter pub get

# Change to the ios directory
cd ios/

# Remove the .symlinks and Pods folders
rm -rf .symlinks
rm -rf Pods

# Run CocoaPods commands
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
pod repo update
pod install

But nothing changed. Do you have an suggestions?

Discover which package version in incompatible with your dart
